# How to remove newline from previous line based on current line's first character?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I exported some data in CSV format that has some line breaks within text fields. I can't get Excel to handle this correctly. I'd like to just edit the file to remove these line breaks.

A valid record begins with a number. I've tried putting `\n^([^\d])` in the "Find what" box of Notepad++'s find/replace, to match any line beginning with a non-number and the preceding newline. It matches correctly. In the "replace with" box, I put a space followed by `\1` to replace the newline with a space and leave the matched character. However, the replace isn't working at all, nothing gets changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Sample text:

```
123,0,1,"This is a single line comment","bob","jim"
124,0,1,"This is a multi line comment w/ newline.
This is the second line of the comment","ted","alfred"
125,0,1,"This is another single line comment","jim","bob"
```

I want to replace the newline just before "This is the second..." with a space so that the file looks like this:

```
123,0,1,"This is a single line comment","bob","jim"
124,0,1,"This is a multi line comment w/ newline. This is the second line of the comment","ted","alfred"
125,0,1,"This is another single line comment","jim","bob"
```

Comment: Can you submit your sample input text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I used `(\n)^(?!\d+,\d+)` to match any newline followed by the beginning of a line that's not followed by at least one number, a comma, and at least one number. In "replace with" I just put a space.

Comment: Thats great. Just tried this in NotePad++ v6.1.6 and it only replaces the LineFeed. It still stays on the next line due to the carriage return. Which version do you have?

Comment: Notepad++ does the same for me, I ended up doing it in Perl and it worked fine as written here.

Answer (score -1):

`\n` works in Notepad++ if you set the linefeeds to `Unix (LF)`.
If it's in `Windows (CR LF)`, then `\r\n` should work, or convert the returns to Unix (from the bottom bar).